# Elegant way of enabling overwritable init function

Tags: c++, c++11

Since once cannot call a *overwritten function* of a *derived class* in *base class constructor*, I would like to emulate this behavior (similar to what C#, Java, ... are doing under the hood).

The most elegant I could come up with (from a signature side of view) is the following:

```
class Base {
protected:
    virtual void init() {
    }

    template <typename T, typename ...U>
    T internal_create(U&& u) {
        T instance(std::forward<U>(u)...);
        instance.init();
        return instance;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
protected:
    Derived() = default;
    virtual void init() override {
    }
public:
    static Derived create() {
        return internal_create<Derived>();
    }


};
```

Where `create` works as a substitute for the constructor (from *public* point of view) and the only way to instantiate an Object.
Question is whether this could be achieved simpler, since now every derived class has to implement `create`.

Comment: You might want to cast an eye over http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-ctors.html

Comment: @TonyDelroy Thx. That approach is IMO very inpractical, since you still can use the default constructor of the classes. Thus the potential for introducing bugs via this mechanism is very high (aside from a weak _coding by convention_ "enforcement").

Comment: @LCIDFire: Then make the default constructor private.  This isn't C, use your constructor as it was meant to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see that your code would compile. And I can't see the point of the virtual `init` method there, although it does suggest two phase construction. Which is just evil, which you can find out more about by reading Bjarne Stroustrup’s [appendix E to “The C++ Programming Language”](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_safe.pdf), especially section E3.5.

The usual methods for doing derived class initialization in a base class constructor are outlined in the [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/calling-virtuals-from-ctor-idiom.html). Since I once convinced Marshall to add that FAQ item, I feel free to also direct you to my own [blog](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/how-to-avoid-post-construction-by-using-parts-factories/).

In the future, remember that it is often a good idea to check out the FAQ first.

---

Oh, I forgot. The point about the C++ rules for dynamic type during construction, is to provide *type safe* construction. In Java and C# you can easily introduce a bug where you're accessing some uninitialized members of a derived class, but not in C++.

Two phase construction ditches that type safety, and makes it difficult to write exception safe usage code, in return for the ability to code it up cleanly for an early 1990's compiler (but really, who needs that ability).

The other usual solutions are designed to keep the type safety.

Comment: Note that with such two-phase construction you re-introduce the a worse opportunity for bugs where you access in phase 1 a variable that you only init in phase 2.